# Sum multiplied values from two different tables then displaying in DataGridView column

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I have three tables in my Access database

```
Part (tbl name)
PartNo
UnitPrice

Order(tbl name)
OrderNo

OrderLine (tbl name)
OrderNo
PartNo
Quantity
```

Basically I want to sum(Quantity by UnitPrice) of all the OrderLines where OrderLine.PartNo = Part.PartNo and OrderLine.OrderNo = Order.OrderNo and place the value in a column I created and added onto the data grid view so it creates a subtotal in the order table on the fly.

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn subtotalCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
subtotalCol.Name = "SubtotalColumn";
subtotalCol.HeaderText = "Subtotal";
subtotalCol.ReadOnly = true;
dataGridViewPrevOrders.Columns.Add(subtotalCol);
```

This is where I am so far but I don't think I'm going about it the right way!

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewPrevOrders.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    connection.Open();
    string orderNo = dataGridViewPrevOrders.Rows[i].Cells["OrderNo"].Value.ToString();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(OL.Quantity * P.UnitPrice) FROM OrderLine OL INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM [Part]) P ON OL.[PartNo] = P.[PartNo] WHERE [OrderNo] = @OrderNo";
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@orderNo", orderNo));
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        dataGridViewPrevOrders.Rows[i].Cells["SubtotalColumn"].Value = reader["Sub"].ToString();
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: Please add the specific problem! Does it lead to an exception? What is the undesired behaviour? Please help us to help you.

On first sight I can only see that you have to correct your sql command to:

```
SELECT SUM(P.UnitPrice * OL.Quantity) AS sumOfOrder FROM Part AS P 
INNER JOIN OrderLine AS OL ON P.[PartNo] = OL.[PartNo] 
WHERE OL.[OrderNo] = @OrderNo;
```

Hint: Regarding your code, it seems to me that you must have an extra SQL-command somewhere to set the Orders to the *dataGridViewPrevOrders*. Then you want to execute an extra SQL command for every Order to calculate the sum. It would be better to query the sum of quantity and OrdersNo with one clever SQL SELECT commmand, where you combine these two Queries and set it in only one loop.